# How to notify a repository about persistence changes

Tags: c#, database, repository, persistence

I have a repository, which at the moment, reads from the database every time it is called. However, the data is only updated once a day, and to improve performance, I'd like the repository to store the data in memory.

When the data is updated, by another application (but same solution), I would like to notify the repository that it should reread the data in the database.

I considered writing a flag to a file, which the repository then reads every time, and rereads the database if true.

Comment: Is the application and repository run in same thread or as same process?

Comment: They are run in different processes.

Comment: Do you know the exact time it updates or you just know it will happen at some stage of the day?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to only be updated once a day? Is it at a specific time?

Comment: I know the approximate time. Give or take 2 hours I think.

Comment: It seems you could use some kind of [Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Reading to/from files is just another way of doing this. That being said, is your application a web application or a forms/wpf application ?

Comment: It is a web application.

Comment: Is there any way in where the producer (which is updating the data) could call a method on your web application to command a refresh on the database cache ?

Comment: @Machado, I suppose that is possible. I am hoping to keep the web application unaware of where the data is coming from if at all possible. It is a of the advantages by having a repository to begin with. Not a bad idea though.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert, you can make it unaware. You just need to add an action to request to "refresh" data. That could be done with a simple "Update" or "Refresh" method exposed on WebApi, and called by anyone outside willing to trigger it. The WebApp would still be unaware of the source of the data, and could just relay the "refresh" command to the repository.

Comment: @Machado, by relaying the command to the repository, it *knows* that the data is now from the database. I grant it is not a direct dependency, but it is a contract dependency.

Comment: @ChrisWohlert, I see. Do you have any service layer in between the repository and the application controller or does the controller calls directly the repository to pull the data ?

Comment: I do, but an *action* to request to refresh the data, would have to be in the application controller.

Comment: Well, the repository is an internal component from the application, right ? Either it have to expose and/or subscribe to external events through some interface, or it has to keep polling the data source from time to time to check if there were any changes on the data. I don't see any way around this.

Comment: When the data changes in the database, update a timestamp. Periodically poll the timestamp.

Comment: What database are you using?  If you are using SQL Server, then you can utilize SQL Dependency and Query Notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What performance issues are you experiencing now ? Remember that you should not deal with these kind of problems before they really become a need.

Read a timestamp from another table. If the timestamp is updated, so is the data.

No need to introduce a flag in a file when you already have access to a database.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the same problem as `how can a server inform a client that data has changed`.

optimized polling:

For http optimisation both client and server have a last known modification date.

when httpclient asks for a http-url it also sends the client-side-last-known-mdoification-date of the url and the server replies either with "you already have the latest data" or with the new data.

assuming that repository-app and modifying-app have access to the same filesystem (i.e. are on the same machine) the modifying-app can set the lastModifiedDate of a known file and the repository app can check the lastModifiedDate of the known file before in-memory-copy is accessed.

I assume that interprocess comunication from server to all known repository-clients is overkill

Answer (score 0):

For web applications/REST APIs, you can use [cache-control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) to specify when you want data to be reread.  There are even proxies you can put in front of your repository that will handle the caching for you.  Basically, you would just have to make a `GET` request with a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header set after your data update happens.

Comment: I am not familiar with these, but it looks to me like the client tells the server when to reread. In this case, the most important thing is that the clients are agnostic to this. The application that knows when data is updated is run on the web server, but in a different process.

Comment: The updater web server process can still make a request like a client after the update completes.